# cross compiling for m68000 (embedded system)

Tags: cross-compilation

How do I cross-compile for a Motorola 68000? The GCC main pages list gcc -m68000 as an option http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/M680x0-Options.html#M680x0-Options, but when I do `gcc -m68000 test.c` it won't work (unknown option). In the past when I cross-compiled I used avr-gcc or msp-gcc, each needing a separate package to be downloaded, but I do not see the like for the m68000. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: The switch does not imply that the m68000 back end is present.  You should track dowm some GNU toolchain for the m68000 and download it.  Then decide if you want to install into any system areas, or keep everything in your own directory and set up the environment variables to run the programs.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~phjk/CompilersCourse/SampleCode/68000/HowToCompileTo68k.html

In this link, I saw that gcc compiler for 68k needs to be called like "gcc-68k"